SweetAlert2 Disappearing when Triggered from Pressing Return
I am using a document.onkeydown to fire when Return is pressed when an element has been tabbed to:
Update:
function detectspecialkeys(e) {
  var evtobj=window.event? event : e; //distinguish between explicit event object (window.event) & implicit
  console.log('Event: ' , evtobj);
  console.log('Code: ' + evtobj.code);
  console.log('Repeat: ' + evtobj.repeat);
  if (evtobj.repeat) {return}
  if ((code==='Space') || (code==='Enter')) { // Space or Return (code:Enter)
    console.log('EObj-Sp/Return: ' , evtobj.target);
    if (evtobj.target.nodeName == 'BUTTON') {
      console.log('Inside Button'); // only see once
      var selid = '#' + evtobj.target.id;
    }
    $(#selid).trigger('singletap');
  }
}
document.onkeydown=detectspecialkeys;

I'm using jQuery Touch Events to handle interactions.
I'm using this version of Sweet Alert2:  https://rahulbhut21.github.io/SweetAlert2/
I can see my handler firing and see the console.log ok:
$('#selid').on('singletap', function(e) {
  console.log('Inside Singletap'); // only see once
  e.preventDefault();
  swal('Test').catch(swal.noop);
  return false;  
});

When I click on #selid, the SweetAlert 2 alert shows fine, but when using the keyboard Return, it flashes and then disappears.  I've tried to implement suggestions mentioned elsewhere, but the alert is still disappearing.

What suggestions did you try from elsewhere? Impossible to rule them out as a suggestion without knowing. For example, sounds like a keydown event issue, as it's likely repeating the key. Have you tried keyup instead? A time limit could also be used to prevent it from firing repeatedly, if for some reason it must be a keydown event.

@l3l_aze  I tried: in singletap - e.preventDefault() & return false;  I'd like to keep it onkeydown event but I've added a .repeat check in there - see update above.  It only runs once, so I assume there's something about Sweet Alert that I am missing - appreciate the assistance.

If you can create a minimal runnable example it may be possible to find the issue. I started trying to set it up, but realized there isn't even enough info here to do so and ran into the usual ES6 import drama with both SA and jQuery, so quickly gave up on that.

@l3l_aze I want to thank you for trying to help - it currently seems like a wasteland in stackoverflow compared to years past when tons of people were helping each other.  I actually discovered that the default action of click events was probably clicking outside of the modal & closing it. Just needed preventDefault & stopPropagation to fix it.

No problem; I'm not amazing at all this, but try to help where possible. Ah, yeah, that makes perfect sense. Should've considered it as I just dealt with similar recently. Lol.

The detectspecialkeys function just needed:
evtobj.preventDefault();
evtobj.stopPropagation();

I believe this was needed as the click event was probably clicking outside of the SweetAlert modal on a parent, due to propagation and thus immediately closing it.
